# TreeSet wont add edges

Tags: java, csv, graph, dijkstra, treeset

i have to code the Dijkstra algorithm. We got a blueprint for this project. Meaning we were told the classes, field variables and methods we have to use.

We have to read the adjacency matrix from a csv file and then use the Dijkstra algorithm.

My problem already begins in in filling the TreeSet edges...

The problem occurs in Graph.class on line 45 when i try to add the Edges.

Example for the csv :

```
;A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H 
A;;1;3;1;;;;  
B;1;;;;3;3;; 
C;3;;;1;;;1; 
D;1;;1;;1;;2; 
E;;3;;1;;1;;5 
F;;3;;;1;;;1 
G;;;1;2;;;;1 
H;;;;;5;1;1; 

=>   
   A ->  (B,1), (C,3), (D,1)
   B ->  (A,1), (E,3), (F,3)
   C ->  (A,3), (D,1), (G,1)
   D ->  (A,1), (C,1), (E,1), (G,2)
   E ->  (B,3), (D,1), (F,1), (H,5)
   F ->  (B,3), (E,1), (H,1)
   G ->  (C,1), (D,2), (H,1)
   H ->  (E,5), (F,1), (G,1)
```

Could somebody look where my problem is ? My indices are correct i checked them with some sout.

Just need help with filling in the TreeSet! I want to try the Dijkstra part myself.

```
 public class Edge implements  Comparable<Edge>{

private int distance;
private Node neighbour;

public Edge(int distance, Node neighbour) {
    this.distance = distance;
    this.neighbour = neighbour;
}

public int getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(int distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}

public Node getNeighbour() {
    return neighbour;
}

public void setNeighbour(Node neighbour) {
    this.neighbour = neighbour;
}


@Override
public int compareTo(Edge o) {
    if (this.neighbour.getId().equals(o.neighbour.getId())){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

}

---

```
     import java.util.TreeSet;
    
     public class Node {
    
         private String id;
         private TreeSet<Edge> edges;
         private int distance;
         private Node previous;
         private boolean isVisited;
    
         public Node(String id) {
             this.id = id;
             this.edges = new TreeSet<>();
         }
    
         public Node(String id, int distance){
             this.id = id;
             this.distance = distance;
         }
    
         @Override
         public String toString() {
             return "Node{" +
                     "id='" + id + '\'' +
                     ", edges=" + edges +
                     ", distance=" + distance +
                     ", previous=" + previous +
                     ", isVisited=" + isVisited +
                     '}';
         }
    
         public String getPath(){
             return null;
         }
    
         public void addEdge(Edge e){
             edges.add(e);
         }
    
         public void init(){
    
         }
    
         public void setStartNode(Node n){
    
         }
    
         public void visit(Node n){
    
         }
    
         public String getId() {
             return id;
         }     
     }
```

---

```
     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
     import java.nio.file.Path;
     import java.util.*;
    
     public class Graph {
    
         private PriorityQueue pq;
         private ArrayList<Node> nodes;
    
         public Graph(){
             this.pq = new PriorityQueue();
             this.nodes = new ArrayList();
         }
    
         public void readGraphFromAdjacencyMatrixFile(Path file) throws FileNotFoundException {
             Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(String.valueOf(file)));
             ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
             ArrayList<Character> nodesCharacter = new ArrayList<Character>();
             while (sc.hasNext()){
                 s.add(sc.next());
             }
             sc.close();
             for(char ch: s.get(0).toCharArray()){
                 if (ch != ';' && ch != ',') {
                     nodes.add(new Node(Character.toString(ch)));
                     nodesCharacter.add(ch);
                 }
             }
             ArrayList<Node> nodes2 = getNodes();
             String node = "";
             int index = 0;
             for (int i = 1; i < s.size(); i++){
                 int cnt = -2;
                 char[] chArray = s.get(i).toCharArray();
                 for (int j = 0; j < chArray.length; j++){
                     if(j == 0){
                         node = String.valueOf(chArray[j]);
                         index = indexOfNode(String.valueOf((chArray[j])));
                     }
                     else if (j >= 2){
                         if (Character.isDigit(chArray[j])){
                             int neighbourIndex = indexOfNode("" + nodesCharacter.get(cnt));
                             Edge e = new Edge(Character.getNumericValue(chArray[j]), nodes.get(neighbourIndex));
                             nodes.get(index).addEdge(e);
                             cnt--;
                         }
                     }
                     cnt ++;
                 }
             }
         }
    
         public String getAllPAths(){
             return null;
         }
    
         public void calcWithDijkstra(String startNodeId){
    
         }
    
         public ArrayList<Node> getNodes() {
             return nodes;
         }
    
         public int indexOfNode(String id){
             int cnt  = 0;
             for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++){
                 if (id.equals(nodes.get(i).getId())){
                     return cnt;
                 }
                 cnt++;
             }
             return -1;
         }
    
     }
```

Comment: Could someone look here pls? 
I added a compareTo to the Edge class but now im stuck in a endless loop

Comment: Your `compareTo` implementation is broken. It needs to be reflexive, transitive and anti-symmetric.